# How does the chromeos shelf determine if linux applications are running?

Tags: linux, google-chrome-os, freedesktop.org

I have a chromebook, with chromeos installed and linux activated.

I have the following files:

`/usr/share/applications/experiment.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Experiment
GenericName=Experiment
Exec=/usr/bin/experiment
Type=Application
```

`/usr/bin/experiment`:

```
#!/bin/sh
sleep 10
notify-send "done"  # sends a pop up notification
```

If I start the application via the ChromeOS launcher, the icon does not stay in the launcher, but `/usr/bin/experiment` is definitively running (evident by the pop up that appears after 10 seconds).

How does ChromeOS determine if an application is running, so the Icon stays in the Shelf?

Answer (score 0):

usually i keep my .desktop files in my home dir under .local/share/applications

is that notify-send binary/script found?
i'd think the /usr/bin/experiment script would be done so the launcher shouldn't show it as running, right?

the launcher started it.  if it's running, the launcher will still have it's pid to show it as running/not.